# pre-loaded content; not requiring Internet access to display new content onclick + mysql submission if connection OK

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

First some background:

I've developed an informal feedback system for disabled learners that collects data and periodically emails out the results as percentages with piecharts.

[QTV http://www.mwjt.co.uk/QTV.jpg](http://www.mwjt.co.uk/QTV.jpg)

Currently it uses 2 PHP webpages:

-The first reads the question from the database.

-The 2nd (a thank-you page) takes the input (as GET) and submits it to the database and then redirects back to the first with an arbitrary random string variable to force full reload (to make sure it's displaying the latest question from the database; these are updated manually using email).

Unfortunately the system is on a wireless connection that occasionally drops. As a result, when a student hits the switch input, a 'no Internet connection' is displayed and then sits there until I remote in and hit refresh.

My question is this:

I'm looking for the best workaround for this dropping connection. I'm not fussed if some entries are not submitted to the DB when the connection is down (it is informal and not totally accurate after all), but I'd always like the cycle of hit a button -> thank-you page displayed -> redirect to question (with check for new question if connection OK, else display previous question) to be consistent.

I'm assuming I somehow need to have both the question and thank-you loaded in one page and have no errors thrown up if submission fails, but I don't know how to proceed.

Many many thanks, Mike

Answer (score 0):

On the first page, when they select any of the choices, have a simple `div` the size of the window pop up and cover the whole page so it *looks* like another page. Write an AJAX script (in the HTML itself) which executes in the background to submit the data. If the internet fails, the AJAX probably will fail, but since the script for the popup is local and has loaded with the HTML already, it *should* still work.